# проблема с редактированием метки leafflet. При нажатии на кнопки сохранить или удалить, создаются новые метки на месте кнопки

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  useMapEvents,
} from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from "leaflet";

const customMarkerIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png",
  iconSize: [25, 32],
  iconAnchor: [12, 32],
  popupAnchor: [0, -32],
});
function MyComponent({ saveMarkers, setNewMarkerData }) {
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click: (e) => {
      const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
      const newMarker = {
        id: Date.now(),
        position: [lat, lng],
        title: "",
        subtitle: "",
        status: "Активный",
      };
      saveMarkers(newMarker);
      setNewMarkerData(newMarker);
    },
  });
  return null;
}

const inactiveMarkerIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: "https://icon-library.com/images/inactive-icon/inactive-icon-8.jpg",
  iconSize: [24, 24],
  iconAnchor: [12, 24],
});

const initialNewMarkerData = {
  id: null,
  position: [0, 0],
  title: "",
  subtitle: "",
  status: "Активный",
};

const Admin = () => {
  const position = [51.145981, 71.471815];
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [newMarkerData, setNewMarkerData] = useState(initialNewMarkerData);
  const [editMarkerIndex, setEditMarkerIndex] = useState(null);
  const [editedMarkerData, setEditedMarkerData] = useState(null);

  const saveMarkers = (newMarker) => {
    const updatedMarkers = [...markers, newMarker];
    setMarkers(updatedMarkers);
    setNewMarkerData(initialNewMarkerData);
  };

  const openEditForm = (id) => {
    const index = markers.findIndex((marker) => marker.id === id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      setEditMarkerIndex(index);
      setEditedMarkerData({ ...markers[index] });
    }
  };

  const saveEdit = (id, editedData) => {
    const updatedMarkers = markers.map((marker) =>
      marker.id === id ? editedData : marker
    );
    setMarkers(updatedMarkers);
    setEditMarkerIndex(null);
    setEditedMarkerData(null);
  };

  const deleteMarker = (id) => {
    const updatedMarkers = markers.filter((marker) => marker.id !== id);
    setMarkers(updatedMarkers);
    setEditMarkerIndex(null);
    setEditedMarkerData(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Карта Админа</h1>
      <MapContainer
        center={position}
        zoom={13}
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        {markers.map((marker) => {
          if (marker.deleted) return null; // Skip rendering deleted markers
          return (
            <Marker
              key={marker.id}
              position={marker.position}
              icon={
                marker.status === "Неактивный"
                  ? inactiveMarkerIcon
                  : customMarkerIcon
              }
              draggable={true}
              eventHandlers={{
                click: () => openEditForm(marker.id),
              }}
            >
              <Popup>
                {editMarkerIndex ===
                markers.findIndex((m) => m.id === marker.id) ? (
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      Заголовок:
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        value={editedMarkerData ? editedMarkerData.title : ""}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          const editedData = {
                            ...editedMarkerData,
                            title: e.target.value,
                          };
                          setEditedMarkerData(editedData);
                        }}
                      />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      Подзаголовок:
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        value={
                          editedMarkerData ? editedMarkerData.subtitle : ""
                        }
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          const editedData = {
                            ...editedMarkerData,
                            subtitle: e.target.value,
                          };
                          setEditedMarkerData(editedData);
                        }}
                      />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      Статус:
                      <select
                        value={editedMarkerData ? editedMarkerData.status : ""}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          const editedData = {
                            ...editedMarkerData,
                            status: e.target.value,
                          };
                          setEditedMarkerData(editedData);
                        }}
                      >
                        <option value="Активный">Активный</option>
                        <option value="Неактивный">Неактивный</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => saveEdit(marker.id, editedMarkerData)}
                    >
                      Сохранить
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => deleteMarker(marker.id)}>
                      Удалить маркер
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div>
                    <strong>{marker.title}</strong>
                    <div>{marker.subtitle}</div>
                    <div>Status: {marker.status}</div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          );
        })}
        <MyComponent
          saveMarkers={saveMarkers}
          setNewMarkerData={setNewMarkerData}
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```